# rails redirect_to after database update

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, parameters

hy, i have a form to change the current language. It is associate an update action in users_controller like this:

```
<%= form_for current_user do |f| %>
 <%= f.select :locale, [['En', 'en'], ['Pt', 'pt']] %>
 <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>


class UsersController < ApplicationController
 def update  
  @user.update(user_params)
  I18n.locale=@user.locale
  redirect_to root_path
 end

 def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:locale)
 end
end
```

After the update i don't want to redirect_to root_path but i want to redirect_to :back but with the locale parameter sets according with the update.
I have no idea, can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

  before_filter :set_locale

  private

  def set_locale
    I18n.locale = current_user ? current_user.locale : 'en'
  end
end
```

Then your update action is just:

```
 def update  
   @user.update(user_params)
   redirect_to :back
 end
```

Comment: not working becouse redirect_to :back is the same to redirect_to request.referrer . In request.referrer there is the request's link with old locale params. Redirect_to :back is ok, but i need to append it the new locale param.

Comment: If you want your users to have their locales set in the profile, I don't think it should be necessary to send locale params. Could you update your question and show how this locale param is being used after redirection?